# joining lines with a specific pattern in a text file

Tags: regex, join, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I'm trying to join rows based on the first value in a row. My file looks like this:

*the structure is: ID, KEY, VALUE*

```
1 1 Joe
1 2 Smith
1 3 30
2 2 Doe
2 1 John
2 3 20
```

The KEY stands for some kind of attribute of the ID, in this case KEY '1' is first name, '2' is surname and '3' is age.

The output should look like this:

```
1 Joe Smith 30
2 John Doe 20
```

I know that this can be done by fairly simple awk script, but I'm having trouble finding it on SO or with Google.

Comment: It is not about what have you found in google or SO but what have you actually tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This awk command should work:

```
awk '$2==1{fn=$3} $2==2{ln=$3} $2==3{age=$3} NR>1 && NR%3==0 {print $1,fn,ln,age}' file
```

Comment: Thanks! What if each ID has more than 3 KEYs? What whould the script look like if there were 7 KEYs per ID? I'm having a bit of trouble understanding it. Or is it for variable amount of KEYs?

Comment: That needs minor adjustments to the script. Instead of `NR%3==0` use `NR%7==0` for 7 fields per ID (`%` is modulo operator).  And of course populate 7 variable instead of 3 I have `fn,ln,age`.

Answer (score 3):

```
{
    a[$1,$2]=$3
    if ($1>m) {m=$1}
}
END {
    for(i=1;i<=m;i++)
    {
        j=1
        printf i " "
        while (a[i,j] != "")
        {
            printf a[i,j] " "
            j++
        }
    printf "\n"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is for variable amount of KEYs, isn't it?

Comment: No, number of keys is `3`.

Comment: What if I have 5 KEYs for example?

Comment: @Dropout fixed, can handle now variable amount of keys. Sorry for the late replay.

Answer (score 2):

One way with `awk`

```
awk '{a[$1]=(a[$1])?a[$1]FS$3:$3}END{for(;x<length(a);)print ++x,a[x]}' <(sort -nk12 file)
```

Comment: Can't use that, unfortunately :(

Comment: @Dropout What was the issue if I may ask?

Comment: Works nice for me, no issues at all!

Comment: but no variable number of KEYs. can not handle `1 4 99` :(

Comment: @Endoro True, the modulus will have to be changed based on keys. Also it is missing the first column which is number of records.

Comment: @Endoro This should be more generic.